# What are the best resources to learn web design for web applications?

Tags: web-applications, user-interface

I've built it now how do I create a half decent design? I need some techniques, resources, examples, books etc. for an information intensive web application.

P.S. - I just bought Web Design for Developers from Pragmatic Programmers and its not very good!

Comment: Are you looking for good aesthetic design or good user interaction?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158769/best-books-to-learn-about-design

Answer (score 2):

i think it's a rather popular question here:

[best-way-to-begin-learning-web-application-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284/best-way-to-begin-learning-web-application-design)

[improve-web-design-skills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133341/improve-web-design-skills)

For books:

[best-books-to-learn-about-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158769/best-books-to-learn-about-design)

[user-interface-design-books-resources-for-programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221966/user-interface-design-books-resources-for-programmers)

And if you haven't read it yet, do read [Don't make me think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107) and [Non designer's design book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321534042) for good page layout design.

Answer (score 1):

I read Designing with Web Standards a long time ago and liked it. I've had the best luck with just hiring a designer, though. If you find a good one, they're well worth the money.